# Git push fork <branch-name> failed

Tags: github, push, git-remote, git-fork, github-issues

Hello i'm trying to create a new PR from existsing repository and I got this arror: "error: src refspec new does not match any"

Here is my steps:

- Step 1 - Create Fork (https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo)
- Step 2 - Create git remote with the following command:
  `git remote add fork https://github.com/MY_USERNAME/SOME_PROJECT.git`
- Step 3 - Commit my work
- Step 4 - Create a new branch with the name: **test**
- Step 5 - Run the following command: `git push fork new computers` and I get this error:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] My problem was at the branch name it should be `new-computers` instand of `new computers`.